# MsiSourceListEnumSources interop c#

Tags: c#, windows-installer, interop

Good Afternoon, I hope that someone can help me i am trying to get the source locations from an installed msi products using the MsiSourceListEnumSources api call.

I always get an invalid_parameter return and cannot figure this out.

```
[DllImport(MSI_LIB, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    internal static extern MsiError MsiSourceListEnumSources(
        string szProductOrPatchCode,
        string szUserSid,
        MsiInstallContext dwContext,
        MsiCode dwOptions,
        int dwIndex,
        [Out] StringBuilder szSource,
        ref int pcchSource);


[Flags]
public enum MsiInstallContext :int
{
    MsiinstallcontextNone = 0,
    MsiinstallcontextUsermanaged = 1,
    MsiinstallcontextUserunmanaged = 2,
    MsiinstallcontextMachine = 4,

    MsiinstallcontextAll =
        (MsiinstallcontextUsermanaged | MsiinstallcontextUserunmanaged | MsiinstallcontextMachine),

    MsiInstallContext_AlluserManaged = 8
}


[Flags]
public enum MsiCode : int
{
    MSICODE_PRODUCT = 0,
    MSISOURCETYPE_NETWORK = 1,
    MSISOURCETYPE_URL = 2
}

 var productCode = "{E636F802-3504-4DE0-92AD-2A47138974FA}";
 var counter = 0;
 int MAX_PATH = 260;
 var strOutPut = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
 int sizeOf = MAX_PATH;
 string EveryOne = "s-1-1-0";
 string sid = UserPrincipal.Current.Sid.ToString();

 var success = MsiInterop.MsiSourceListEnumSources(
            productCode, null, MsiInstallContext.MsiinstallcontextMachine , MsiCode.MSICODE_PRODUCT , counter,  strOutPut, ref sizeOf );
```

I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong, i have tried or felt like a hundred and one different combinations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Change `CharSet.Auto` to `CharSet.Unicode`.

Comment: Would you be interested in a library that already has all of this?

Comment: Always interested into looking at options.

Comment: Tried changing the CharSet to Unicode and i still get Invalid Parameter, looking at the msdn doc - seems to be due to productCode or sid parameters and context of installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
[DllImport("msi", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int MsiSourceListEnumSourcesW(string pc,string sid, MsiInstallContext ctx, MsiCode opts, int index,  [Out] StringBuilder szResult, ref int len);
}
```

together with your enumerations and this call:

```
int len = 16384;
StringBuilder thing = new StringBuilder(null, len); 
int rf = MsiInvoke.MsiSourceListEnumSourcesW(ProdCode, null, 
                MsiInvoke.MsiInstallContext.MsiinstallcontextMachine,
                MsiInvoke.MsiCode.MsiProdN,
                0, 
                thing,
                ref len);
```

The error in your code appears to be that you can't just set the MSICODE_PRODUCT flag, you must set a sourcetype flag, and the network flavor works.

Comment: Thank you so much just tested and now is working, i wouldnt have test adding more flags a little bit frustrating. Why do i always find MS documentation so frustrating. Just for other users I create a Combine on the MSICOMBINE = MSICODE_PRODUCT | MSISOURCETYPE_NETWORK